# 403 Forbidden - Nginx - oracle cloud instance

Tags: nginx, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I want a public access to my uploads folder for example:

> mydomain.com/uploads/

It needs to show the dir whats in there for example:

> mydomain2.com/uploads/id/file.png

this should show the file.png

but when i tried

> mydomain2.com/uploads/

it gives me

> 403 Forbidden
>   nginx/1.15.1

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# mydomain1.com
server {
    listen   443;
    ssl                 on;
    ssl_certificate     /home/opc/Crt/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/opc/Crt/mydomain1.key;

    server_name mydomain1;
    #root <root_path>;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

#mydomain2.com

server {

  # We are listening on the default port.
  listen 443;

  ssl                 on;
  ssl_certificate     /home/opc/Crt/bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/opc/Crt/mydomain2.com.key;

  # These are the domains we listen on.
  server_name mydomain2.com;

  # The root path
  #root <physical_path>

  location /uploads {
    #internal;
    alias /home/opc/folder/uploads;
    #try_files $uri /uploads/;
    #autoindex on;
    #index index.html;
    #autoindex on;
    #autoindex_exact_size off;
 }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

> note: 2 domains are pointed to my instance so I am using one for 3001 port and other for 3000 port and also i have given 755 to /folder/uploads and 644 to all files inside uploads folder

Comment: Check nginx error log located in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and paste the line cooresponding to that 403 error

Comment: @DusanGligoric `*43 "/home/opc/folder/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 42.201.145.42, server: mydomain2.com, request: "GET /uploads/ HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain2.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your nginx process does not have permissions to access that folder/file, check permissions on the `/home/opc/folder/index.html`. Do `chown nginx:nginx /home/opc/folder/index.html` and run same request, see how it goes, if it still has issues you probably have some kernel access control like SELinux, if you run on CentOS and first test fails do `chcon -R --reference=/usr/share/nginx/html/ /home/opc/folder` and try again.